# How to fix Error "OleAut reported a type mismatch" when using Countif in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-interop

I am trying to use function COUNTIF at column B (CustomerName) in table "Products". But I get an error. 
Can anyone help why I am getting error and how to fix it.
Thank you so much.
[image]
[image]

```
void Duplicate()
        {
            int ketqua = 1;
            Double t;
            GetActiveExcelFile();
            Excel.Worksheet esh = oWB.Worksheets["Order detail"];            
            long lastRow;
            lastRow = esh.Cells[esh.Rows.Count, 2].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
            Excel.Application a = new Excel.Application();
            if (lastRow == 55)
                for (int i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++)
                {
                    Excel.Range objRange = (Excel.Range)esh.Cells[i, 2];
                    String strData = objRange.get_Value(System.Type.Missing).ToString(); //get the value cell[i,2]
                    if (strData != "")
                    {
                        t = a.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(esh.get_Range("B2","B55"), strData);
                        if (t > 1)
                        {
                            ketqua = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            ketqua = 0;
                    }
                }            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use always objects, or ranges in excel

//t = a.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(esh.get_Range("B2","B55"), strData);

t = a.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(esh.get_Range("B2","B55"), (Excel.Range)esh.Cells[i, 2]);

2. OS language vs numberformat
   use the default numberformat on your system

Answer (score -2):

I believe it is when you created a new Excel.Application. That's what my problem was. You are referencing an already declared worksheet varaible on a new application. I'm new to coding so hopefully that helps.

Comment: This looks more like a comment. If its an answer, adding a web-resource to back your answer might help.